# Reordering items (left to right) onclick ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the following code I reorganize a list from bottom to top or from top to bottom.

I would rather be able to reorganize it from left to right.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

[image]

App

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FruitList from "./FruitList";
const UP = -1;
const DOWN = 1;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // set new state for bind key items
    items: [
      { id: 1, name: "orange", bgColor: "#f9cb9c" },
      { id: 2, name: "lemon", bgColor: "#fee599" },
      { id: 3, name: "strawberry", bgColor: "#e06666" }
    ]
  };

  handleMove = (id, direction) => {
    const { items } = this.state;

    const position = items.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
    if (position < 0) {
      throw new Error("Given item not found.");
    } else if (
      (direction === UP && position === 0) ||
      (direction === DOWN && position === items.length - 1)
    ) {
      return; // canot move outside of array
    }

    const item = items[position]; // save item for later
    const newItems = items.filter(i => i.id !== id); // remove item from array
    newItems.splice(position + direction, 0, item);

    this.setState({ items: newItems });
  };

  render() {
    return <FruitList fruitList={this.state.items} onMove={this.handleMove} />;
  }
}
export default App;
```

My components

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
const UP = -1;
const DOWN = 1;
class FruitList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fruitList, onMove } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {fruitList.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id} style={{ backgroundColor: item.bgColor }}>
            <div className="fruitsId">{item.id}</div>
            <div className="fruitsName">{item.name}</div>
            <div className="fruitsArrows">
              <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, UP)}>&#x25B2;</a>
              <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, DOWN)}>&#x25BC;</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FruitList;
```

Comment: What do you mean by moving the item from left to  right? I mean if you change the index, the item will only move up or down? Can you elaborate what exactly is your use case?

Comment: @MohammadHaseeb 
yes of course, then I would like it to react exactly the same as from top to bottom except from left to right I link you a photo to better understand

Comment: Is it enough to just style it? An ordered list is no different going up/down or left/right. Indexes don't know direction? Just use css(flexbox, orientation) to place them horizontal? Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using css flexbox.

I applied `{ display: "flex" }` to the root div in FruitList. (The direction is default row).

FruitList.js

```js
class FruitList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fruitList, onMove } = this.props;

    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {fruitList.map(item => (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: item.bgColor,
              display: "flex",
            }}
          >
            <div className="fruitsArrows">
              <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, LEFT)}>&#8592;</a>
            </div>
            <div className="fruitsId">{item.id}</div>
            <div className="fruitsName">{item.name}</div>
            <div className="fruitsArrows">
              <a onClick={() => onMove(item.id, RIGHT)}>&#8594;</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-itl2dq?embed=1&file=FruitList.js)